# CSS opacity effecting the child divs

Tags: html, css

I tried the `opacity` with the help of [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity). It does work well, except for one thing. The div where I want to use the opacity has other contents in it too. So, when I use `opacity` in that parent div, the child div also gets effected! What to do so as to effect only the parent div and not the child divs? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

html:

```
<div id="profile_rightbar">

            <div id="shortcuts">
                <div class="icon pink">
                    <a href="#">
                        <p>Pictures</p>
                        <p>210</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="icon green">
                    <a href="#">
                        <p>Videos</p>
                        <p>210</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="icon blue">
                    <a href="#">
                        <p>Forums</p>
                        <p>210</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="icon orange">
                    <a href="#">
                        <p>Pages</p>
                        <p>210</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="icon pink">
                    <a href="#">
                        <p>Followers</p>
                        <p>210</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="icon green">
                    <a href="#">
                        <p>Following</p>
                        <p>210</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="status">
                <p>Always do your best. What you plant now, you will harvest later.</p>
            </div>

            <div id="write">
                <textarea id="redactor" name="content">
        <h2>Hello and Welcome</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </textarea>
            </div>

            <div id="activity">

                <div class="picture">
                    <a href="#">
                        <p>The world is so perfect. How can one not love this beautiful world.</p>
                        <img src="image/world.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="picture">
                    <a href="#">
                        <p>The world is so perfect. How can one not love this beautiful world.</p>
                        <img src="image/world.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="forum">
                    <a href="#">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="video">
                    <a href="#">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="page">
                    <a href="#">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="following">
                    <a href="#">
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>


        </div>
        <div class="clear_right"></div>
```

css:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#main_wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:url(../image/pantera.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
       -moz-background-size: cover;
        -ms-background-size: cover;
         -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
}

#profile_page {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#username h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

#profile_leftbar {
    width: 210px;
    float: left;
}

#profile_picture {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
}

#profile_picture img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: none;
    max-width:190px;
    padding: 8px;
}

#about {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
}

#about p {
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}

#about hr {
    height:1px;
    border:0px solid ;
    border-top:1px solid #ccc;
}

#follow_message {
    width: 210px;
    margin: 5px auto;
}

#follow_message li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 3px;

}

#follow_message a {
    display: block;
    width: 101px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 30px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 2px 0;
    background: maroon;
}





#profile_rightbar {
    float: right;
    width: 590px;
}

#shortcuts {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 588px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#shortcuts div {
    float: left;
    margin: 4px;
}

.icon a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 88px;
    padding: 1px;
}

.icon a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.pink a {
    background-color:#d63175;
}

.green a {
    background-color:#51b73c;
}

.blue a {
    background-color:#2f8ae0;
}

.orange a {
    background-color:#f7a809;
}

#status {
    background-color:white;
    box-shadow:5px 5px 20px 1px black;
    max-width:490px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    padding:6px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:30px;
    line-height: 32px;
}

#write {
    width: 575px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#write textarea {
    font-size:20px;
    max-width:575px;
    width: 575px;
}

#activity {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 575px;
}

#activity {
    border: solid red;
    opacity: 0.2;
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);       /* IE8 and lower */
    zoom: 1; 

#activity div {
    background: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#activity .picture a img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 540px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.picture a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.picture a p {
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-left:15px;
}
```

Comment: `opacity` will always affect the child/descendant elements. If you want to stick with `opacity`, you could make a sibling element to your "parent div", and move the parent div styling to that sibling element, then position this sibling element such that it's where the parent div also is, so it *appears as* the parent div (the parent div would appear invisible, so you can see the sibling div). Then you can set opacity on that sibling element, which will affect only it, and not the descendant elements of the original parent div.

Comment: @ajp15243 Thank you for your help. Could you please elaborate a little more, or if possible answer it here. Thanks again.

Comment: @AlienArrays I am sorry I thought it will be helpful.

Comment: @Robin I think the easier way is to simply make a transparent PNG background image that you can tile in your parent div in place of the `opacity` property, as suggested by x4rf41 in the comments of Girish Gowda's answer. There are plenty of tutorials out there for making one (you'll typically need advanced image editing software, but [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) is free). Or you might be able to find one to download, but then you won't have a custom-made one, which may be fine if you find one you like. This way might be slightly more complicated, but will result in much cleaner code.

Answer (score 1):

dont use opacity it affects all child elements

Use 
    `background-color : rgba(255,255,255,0.2);`

which blurs only the parent element.

Comment: an easy way to make this compatible for old browsers which dont support `rgba` is to create a 20% opacity white png and use it as a background picture (i think thats ie6+)

Comment: @x4rf41 I think you'd need a PNG fix for IE6 (and 7?), but barring that, a transparent PNG will definitely give old browser compatibility.

Comment: im 100% sure pngs work fine on ie7, not sure about 6 though, you might be right. but at that point, you cant do anything anyway

Comment: I think one can also use proprietary Microsoft filters for opacity in older IE browsers, which is easier than a PNG (at least, once you look up and copy/paste the code :P).

Comment: @x4rf41 I thought of using PNG, just had some doubts. Will effect the performance? Thank you for the comment thought.

Comment: @ajp15243 Could you please the microsoft filters?

Comment: @Robin [This article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/) lists a variety of ways to target different browsers for some sort of opacity rule. This will (probably) not solve your original problem, the fact that it affects descendant elements, as the rules in that article are not background rules like `rgba()` is.

Comment: @Robin i would suggest using a 20x20 to 40x40 png to reduce repetitions (dont use 1x1). other than that, i dont think the performance is an issue here (its the most common way to use transparent backgrounds on old browsers)

Comment: Agreed on performance, there shouldn't be much if any noticeable performance hit.

Comment: @Robin, yes i missed it. But i think you got solution. Thanks guys

Comment: @ajp15243 Thanks for the article I will sure look on it.

Comment: @x4rf41 Thank you for your help. I guess I will use PNG now.